# Safe transactions are getting failed when executed through relay(Sponsored Call)

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core, safe, gelato

I'm trying to execute a Safe transaction through the relay. The transaction has enough signatures, it just needs to be executed. After a few seconds, the transaction status changes to Cancelled  and it says "lastCheckMessage":"Execution error: GelatoRelay.sponsoredCall:GS020" - Does anyone know what I'm missng or what GS020 means?

Simulation on tenderly also getting failed. this is the tenderly simulation link
https://dashboard.tenderly.co/harsha/project/simulator/81d15adb-187c-41a5-a6ad-9f9b203db9be

```
        const safeTransactionData = {
            oldOwnerAddress,
            newOwnerAddress,
        };

        const safeSDK = await Safe.create({
            ethAdapter,
            safeAddress,
        });

        const options: MetaTransactionOptions = {
            gasLimit: "100000",
            isSponsored: true,
        };

        const safeTransaction = await safeSDK.createSwapOwnerTx(safeTransactionData);

        const relayPack = new GelatoRelayPack(GELATO_API_KEY);

        const response = await relayPack.executeRelayTransaction(
            safeTransaction,
            safeSDK,
            options,
        );

        const gelatoTaskId = response.taskId;
        const explorerUrl = gelatoTaskId && (await handleTransactionStatus(gelatoTaskId));
```

Code is as given above.

Answer (score 1):

GS020 error means that there are not enough signatures sent to the contract:

- When the error is thrown: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/f03dfae65fd1d085224b00a10755c509a4eaacfe/contracts/Safe.sol#L312
- Meaning of the Error code: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/f03dfae65fd1d085224b00a10755c509a4eaacfe/docs/error_codes.md?plain=1#L15

Given your code, the threshold should be 1 and the EthAdapter you are using should be initialized with an owner of your Safe. The issue is happening because one of these conditions is not met.

Comment: Yes, signing part of the code was missing here. it's working fine on updating the code.    Thanks German.

Answer (score 0):

Signing part was missing here. here is the working code.

```
    const safeTransactionData = {
        oldOwnerAddress,
        newOwnerAddress,
    };

    const safeSDK = await Safe.create({
        ethAdapter,
        safeAddress,
    });

    const options: MetaTransactionOptions = {
        gasLimit: "100000",
        isSponsored: true,
    };

    const safeTransaction = await safeSDK.createSwapOwnerTx(safeTransactionData);

    const signedSafeTransaction = await safeSDK.signTransaction(safeTransaction);

    const relayPack = new GelatoRelayPack(GELATO_API_KEY);

    const response = await relayPack.executeRelayTransaction(
        safeTransaction,
        safeSDK,
        options,
    );

    const gelatoTaskId = response.taskId;
    const response = gelatoTaskId && (await 
    handleTransactionStatus(gelatoTaskId));
```

}

Thanks [@German](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/89118/germ%c3%a1n)